# laravel9 でDB内の json データから値を抽出して利用する方法

Tags: mysql, laravel

laravel9 のDBでテーブルの一部にjson形式でデータを保存しています。
json形式のデータから「特定のキー」の値だけを抜き出して、出力用のデータを作ろうとしています。

目的のデータは下記のSQLを実行することで得ることが確認できました。

```
SELECT jt.value
FROM logs
CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(
    logs.query,
    '$' COLUMNS ( value text PATH '$.name')
) jt
```

しかしながら、このSQLをLaravel上ではどのように表現するのか分からずにいます。
下記のようなコードを書いてみましたが、エラーになってしまいます。

```
$q= LogAction::query()->selectRaw(
    "DISTINCT jt.value,
    JSON_TABLE(logs.query,
    '$' COLUMNS( value TEXT PATH '$.{$request->key}')
    ) AS jt");
$q->get();
```

`SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'JSON_TABLE(logs.query, '$'`

$query->toSql() で確認すると次のようなsqlが発行されていました

```
select DISTINCT jt.value,
                JSON_TABLE(logs.query,
                '$' COLUMNS( value TEXT PATH '$.name')
                ) AS jt from `logs`
```

このような場合にどのように対応すればよろしいでしょうか？
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

Modelクラスを利用しないのであれば下記で同様のクエリを実行できます。
$logsには結果セットが返ってくるので、foreachで各行の値を取得できます。

```php
$query =
"SELECT jt.value
FROM logs
CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(
    logs.query,
    '$' COLUMNS ( value text PATH '$.name')
) jt";

$logs = DB::select(DB::raw($query));
```

Answer (score 1):

JSONカラムの特定のキーは`->`で直接指定できる。

```php
$users = DB::table('users')
                ->where('preferences->dining->meal', 'salad')
                ->get();
```